# How to deal with this answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, self-answer

**SCENARIO**
 Surfing in SO, I found the question and downvoted it but upvoted the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818706/how-to-find-repeat-elements-in-array

The question has been closed as dupe by [Gayan Ranaweera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869846/ruchira-gayan-ranaweera) like 1 minute after. I thought was a nice upvote for the answer, since I've realized, **OP itself has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29818731/3850595) it's own dupe question in less than a minute**.

**QUESTION**
Should we **upvote** the answer (as is a valid answer), or should we **downvote** it (as OP posted it in a minute) ?

Comment: My point is if answer is valid no need to downvote. But If the question is not beneficial some one else we can flag the question.

Comment: If that's an attempt at a self-answered question (and anything else seems unrealistic, I doubt OP wrote and posted this code in 57 seconds), it's a rather useless one. Deletion of the question seems like the best idea; if OP thinks his answer adds anything that's not yet written in the dupe then he should answer there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Evaluate the question and answer that you see on their own merits. If a self-answered question is a duplicate, close it as a duplicate. Is the answer good in spite of the fact that the question is a duplicate? Feel free to upvote it. Or if the answer is incorrect or otherwise not useful, downvote it.

But **do not** downvote an answer **just because the asker posted it along with the question** (and most certainly **do not flag the posts as spam**, unless [the content itself fits our definition of spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035)). There is nothing wrong with [answering your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) — the ability to post a question and an answer simultaneously is even [built into the site as a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) (though the OP did not use the feature in this case, I'm just going to assume they were unaware of it and thought they had to manually post the answer immediately after the question). This is a perfectly normal use of the site that it is incredibly unfair to punish users for doing.

Answer (score -6):

IMHO, OP might have done it by purpose or by mistake. If by purpose, there should be some penalty. If by mistake, penalty should be there anyway in order to prevent such future occurrences.

After all, nothing changes so drastically that someone fighting for a solution so much that he posted it on SO; not only find the answer, but think it's efficient as well ('It an easily and efficiently be done by hash map') - all of that in less than 60 seconds. What just happened there? A miracle ?

Comment: No, just someone who had an answer and wanted to share it, so also created the question?

Comment: First, it's not what we use SO for. Secondly, in that case, the problem / code must be of very high value / epic!

Comment: "First, it's not what we use SO for." That's where you're mistaken: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange